# Posix message queue issue about sending message

Tags: c, posix, message-queue, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to send a message from child process to parent process using POSIX message queues. I created the message queue before I created children using fork(). My code is supposed to take words from the linked list and send them to the parent. However, when I call the mq_send function to send data, program gets stuck in the function, tries to take input from the console and never stops. I have been working on this problem for more than day and I could not figure out how to do it. I checked the other parts of the code and they all work. Only the mq_send function causes a problem. Can somebody tell me what is the problem here? Maybe I am missing something. The code is below.

Note: I cannot include all the code here. Only parts relevant to the problem is here. Also, this is my first question in stackoverflow so I am sorry about possible formatting errors.

Edit: The code cannot be compiled because I did not add all the parts. My question is only based on the last while loop of the code where the message is sent. That is where the code gets stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/msg.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

struct Node {
    char value[1024];
    int count;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct dataPackage {
    char word[1024];
    int count;
};


int main(int argcount, char** argvalues) {
    struct Node* headList[atoi(argvalues[1])];      // an array to hold linked lists   
    
    // creating fileCount number of linked lists and storing them
    for ( int i = 0; i < atoi(argvalues[1]); i++ ) {
        headList[i] = NULL;
    }

    // creating message queues
    mqd_t mqList[fileCount];
    char queueNames[5][1024];
    int n;
    // creating different names for different message queues

    strcpy(queueNames[0], "/queue1");
    strcpy(queueNames[1], "/queue2");
    strcpy(queueNames[2], "/queue3");
    strcpy(queueNames[3], "/queue4");
    strcpy(queueNames[4], "/queue5");

    // creating the message queues
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argvalues[1]); i++ ) {
        mqList[i] = mq_open(queueNames[i], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL ); 
        printf("%i\n", mqList[i]); 
    }

    // creating child processes to process input files
    
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argvalues[1]); i++ ) {
        
        // creating a child process
        pid_t pid = fork();
        
        // child processes process seperate files
        if (pid == 0 ) {
            //printf("Before file process\n");
            // processing the file and creating the sorted linked lists
            processFile(fileNames[i], &headList[i]);
            
            // send linked list contents to parent process below
            struct dataPackage package;
            struct Node* tempHead = headList[i];
            
            while (tempHead != NULL) {
                // creating a package to send it to the parent process
                package.count = tempHead->count;
                strcpy(package.word, tempHead->value);
                
                // !!!!!this is the part where the program gets stuck!!!!!!!!
                n = mq_send(mqList[i], (char*) &package, sizeof(struct dataPackage), 0);
                tempHead = tempHead -> next;
            }
            // creating a message that will indicate the end of message queue
            package.count = -10;
            strcpy(package.word, "stop");
            n = mq_send(mqList[i], (char *) &package, sizeof(struct dataPackage), 0);
            exit(0);
        }   
        else {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char** argvalues` `struct Node* headList[argvalues[1]];` an array with the size of a `char*`? What do you believe that line does? `i < argvalues[1]` comparison between a `int` and a `char*`? Don't you get a wall of warnings from your compiler? Be sure to fix them all. `i < atoi(argvalues[1])` och? `I cannot include all the code here` Why not? Providing an [MCVE] will get you help faster.

Comment: Your code does not compile as provided so it's hard to identify what might be the actual problem.  You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @KamilCuk I was in a hurry while copying the code. It is actually i < atoi(argvalues[1]). I think the problem is in the last while loop where I send the message. The program gets stuck there. I think I am missing something in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the mq_receive call. There is a queue limit imposed by the system which you should be able to see by doing something like  cat /dev/mqueue/mymq once your message queue is estabilished. That is to say, I would check that you are consuming your messages correctly. What I see your code doing is spawning as many childrens as whatever the value is in argvalues[1] having the child mq_send, but the parent just waits for the child to die without consuming the messages.

https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview

Comment: Children only process a given input file, generate and send contents of it to parent using message queue and they are terminated using exit(0). I did not include the receive part because program does not move forward from mq_send function. I think problem is in there.

Comment: Exactly, "then, by default, mq_send() blocks until sufficient space becomes available to allow the message to be queued" so if you are not consuming the messages, you will get stuck on mq_send. So I would check your mq_receive logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check out the mq_receive once again now but there is one problem. Assignment tells me to send messages inside child processes and the receive can only occur after all child processes are terminated. So I will have to continuously send messages without receiving. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The messages will stay in the queue even when it is closed. To empty a message queue the messages must be read out, or the queue destroyed (unlink). In fact, your problem may be that the queue is full from prior runs of your program without proper mq_receive. e.g. you send 3 times but recv 2 times your queue will fill up after # runs and block on send. Also, check your limits as mentioned in the mq_overview, if you only have space for one message and need to send three you will also get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 struct Node* headList[argvalues[1]];
```

makes me wonder what you want to achieve. `argvalues[1]` is a pointer-to-char, not a number. Your compiler should have told you this.

If you want the first argument to be converted to a number, you should use something like

```
int count;
if (sscanf(argvalues[1], "%d", &count) != 1) {
     /* does not look like a number */
     exit(1);
}
/* use count */
```

Comment: Yes. I was in a hurry while copying the code. It is actually atoi(argvalues[1]). Purpose of the code is to read and process files using child processes and to send them to parent process. I did not include whole code because not all parts are relevant to  my question. Actually only the final loop in the code is directly related to the question.

Comment: @suleyman6001 Then please edit your code to make it compile. Never ever give us modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the queue you try to access is not full of messages.

Use `mq_getattr()` and `mq_curmsgs` to determine the current number of messages.

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of this method in use?